# QGIS version incompatibility

Tags: qgis, layers

I have been using QGIS Madeira on Surface and Desktop but had to reload Win 10 on Desktop.  Reloaded QGIS but it's now Coruna.  Coruna will not load Maps saved in Madeira, the basic map will load but the extra layers do not.  Is there a fix?

I get a dialogue box listing offending layers with "Keep Unavailable Layers", "Remove Unavailable Layers" and "Apply Changes". If I "Keep" they are loaded with warning triangle. If I hover over the layer name in layer panel it says "Layer data source couldn't be found. Click to set a new data source". These layers took a long time to draw and I don't have the time to redo.

I tried to find a copy of Madeira to download but could only find on sites I wouldn't trust, any suggestions for a safe site to download Madeira?

Comment: What is wrong with the tab "all releases" at https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html#? Also, without further details on your layers, where you saved them, possible error messages, etc. we wont be able to help you.

Comment: Missed "all releases", trying that now.  The layers that do not load are vector layers (line string) drawn in Madeira and showing as *.gpkg if hovered over in Madeira layers list.

Comment: I get a dialogue box listing offending layers with "Keep Unavailable Layers", "Remove Unavailable Layers" and "Apply Changes".  If I "Keep" they are loaded with warning triangle.  If I hover over the layer name in layer panel it says "Layer data source couldn't be found.  Click to set a new data source".  These layers took a long time to draw and I don't have the time to redo.

Comment: The problem may also come from the location of your .gpkg, if all the layer that didn't draw came from the same .gpkg that's the more likely explanation. Check that it has not been displaced or that some folder have not been renamed.

Comment: I thought the qgz file contained everything, what should I be looking for please?  I downloaded Madeira but still get same problem, so where are the missing files?

Comment: The files are whereever you saved them. QGIS-project files are - unlike CAD-files - only a bunch of links to the data you want them to display.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't know that.  QGIS is very good but there is a very steep learning curve attached.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT :

Following the comment your problem come from your new installation. The data used to draw the map have a different path and QGIS can't find them. When you try to open your map you should get the "Handle Bad Layers" dialog where you have to input the data new location

If you trust the official QGIS site go there :[All version](https://qgis.org/downloads/) (the version are listed by version number, not by name that could be why you couldn't find the right download link)

An alternative could be to use the OSGeo4W installer.

See [here](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#windows) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

You say

> I get a dialogue box listing offending layers with "Keep Unavailable Layers", "Remove Unavailable Layers" and "Apply Changes". If I "Keep" they are loaded with warning triangle. If I hover over the layer name in layer panel it says "Layer data source couldn't be found. Click to set a new data source". These layers took a long time to draw and I don't have the time to redo.

This simply says, that your project doesn't know, where the data is saved. **This is definitely not a problem of your software version.**

Possible sources of the problem and their solutions:

- you changed the path to your project while having it saved using absolute paths - when opening the project you can correct the path to all faulty layers in the very window you described
- you changed the path to your data - solution as above
- you deleted your data - try restoring it via the usual options available in windows

Comment: I understand what the problem is now, I just used the qgz file from the Surface Book as everything had been lost from the Desktop.

Comment: I have a supplementary question.  What is the correct procedure for transferring from one computer to another so that data does not get left behind?

Comment: The answer is rather trivial: Save it in an obvious place (e.g., have a standard project folder where the data is saved in subfolders) and then copy it.

Comment: Might seem trivial to you but I've lost data on one computer and can't retrieve it from another despite copying all related files.